# Firefox extension can't add request headers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, request, header, firefox-addon

I'm trying to port a browser extension from Chrome to Firefox using `webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener` but any attempts to add request headers to requests don't work. If I modify the code to cancel requests rather than add request headers then the requests are cancelled as expected, so I don't think there are any issues with the permissions and options. The extension's manifest has the `webRequest`, `webRequestBlocking`, and site permissions granted in the extension's manifest JSON. Here's the code in question:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(() => ({ requestHeaders: [ { name: "x-test", value: "abc" } ] }), { urls: [ "https://example.com/*" ] }, [ "blocking" ]);
```

Any help would be appreciated!